# Trade Count Time Series

Tags: trade, time

Is historical information on the counts of trades in single stocks, futures, options etc. available somewhere for download or purchase? If not, which ways can you think of to gather it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactive Brokers provides it as a field called `count`.

In [this page](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/c/historicaldata.htm) of the [IB API Reference Guide](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/api.htm) `count` is described as follows

> When TRADES historical data is returned, represents the number of trades that occurred during the time period the bar covers.

Comment: Ok, so IB provides this data. Nice. This is not an option if you do not trade via IB, but for me and, I believe, many others this is ok.

Comment: You asked if the data was "available somewhere for download or purchase."  You don't have to make any trades in order to get the data although you may have to pay something like 10 or 20 dollars a month.  You _may_ even be able to get the data with a paper trading account for free.

Comment: I am undecided which answer to accept. Since I believe that IB offers a lot of asset classes and exchanges and the count is supposedly then available for all history, I opt for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Its not available for free anywhere that I know of.  Your only option is to purchase tick data for the instruments you're interested in and then count the ticks per trading session (or whichever timeframe you want to use).

EDIT: This link might be interesting for you regarding how to get market data.

http://www.quantshare.com/sa-426-6-ways-to-download-free-intraday-and-tick-data-for-the-us-stock-market

Comment: Yes, I stumbled upon this link yesterday and figured that simply loading tick data might give a hint - how to interpret ticks? It is not the BBO I get, but the prices of trades that happened, right?

Comment: @Konsta You said you are trying to count trades, right?  Each tick is one trade.  So for a daily bar, just count the total number of ticks that happen in that day.  Note that this is different from the total volume, which would be the sum of the trade size of each tick (like 300 shares, etc).